# Dijkstra and one question on analysis, is it related to implementation?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, graph, tree

What is the amortized update cost for each vertex in `Dijkstra` algorithm:

Answer: `O(|E| / |V|)`

My challenge is that:

> this answer relate to implementation or not? i.e: fib heap or...  and
> next this relate to which operation of Dijkstra algorithm? I means
> decrease key? remove min part? which part of analysis?

consider for example this pesudocode just for discuss (or any others):

[image]

Comment: Amortization makes fairly little sense for Dijkstras algorithm. And in either way, the complexity is `O(|E| + |V| log |V|)`, so idk what that got divided by to wind up with `O(|E| / |V|)`. Overall this looks like a wrong answer to a question that doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: @Paul very thanks, but please make a little more clear me? can we say there is O(E) update at most in Dijkstra occurred? for each vertex at most 1 time?

Comment: Echoing @Paul, the reason that this question makes little sense is that Dijkstra's algorithm isn't a data structure with many possible call sequences; it just does its thing and then exits. With a Fibonacci heap, which has amortized time bounds, the amortized work done by the heap inside the loop for a vertex u is O(degree(u)).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat very nice. would you please add as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Echoing @Paul, this question doesn't make a lot of sense because Dijkstra's algorithm isn't a data structure with many possible call sequences; it just does its thing and then exits.

If we assume a Fibonacci heap, whose operations has amortized time bounds, the amortized work done by the heap inside the loop for a vertex u is O(degree(u)), since Fibonacci heaps have amortized constant-time decrease key operations.

If you really want, you can further amortize the cost by defining an additional potential function on the order of (sum of degrees of nodes in the heap)/2 − (number of nodes in the heap times |E|/|V|). This potential function goes from zero to zero, and it makes the amortized cost of each decreasekey O(|E|/|V|).

Comment: two question: at first Deg(U) is at most |E| am I right?

Comment: Even better, the sum of deg(u) for all u is 2 |E|.

Comment: one point is missed for me. in whole running of Dijkstra all update for all  vertex is 2 |E|? or |E|? this is my problem infact.

Comment: I means in Dijkstra's algorithm there are |E| update operations ?

Comment: @JohnatanMorian deletemin costs log |V| per invocation, |V| log |V| total, hence the running time is O(|E| + |V| log |V|).

Comment: I'm so sorry. I know you are so expert. but my challenge is this question? in Dijkstra's algorithm there are |E| update operations  at all is correct?

Comment: @JohnatanMorian at most |E| decreasekey operations, yes, since each edge will be relaxed in only one direction.

Comment: so my fact is correct? There are |E| decrease key operation at most occurred in Dijkstra then |E| / |V| is the amortized bound of update for each vertex? is it correct? thanks.

Comment: @JohnatanMorian It could be, but you'd have to do the amortization a bit strangely.

Comment: So would you please update the answer to accept? exactly I need a correct idea.

Comment: thanks and my last question when I read your update answer is that we know amortized of fib heap is O(1) for decrease key and the update is at most |E| then total amortized is |E| divide by |N|? is it stronger or incorrect too?

Comment: @JohnatanMorian You can't do better than that -- some graphs require all edges to be relaxed.